# python anaconda - manage module for different python versions

Tags: python, anaconda, aiohttp

I have 2 version of `Python` in my mac(2.7 and 3.5.1) in my Anaconda. When every I

```
pip install xxx
```

it will automatically go into `/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages` folder. 
Now I want to learn `aiohttp` and when I install it

```
pip install aiohttp
```

it will give me error:

> raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.1+")
>       RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.1+
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> ```
>
> /private/var/folders/c2/3yxfnvc51fng531jz312t00m0000gn/T/pip-build-m_mCpM/aiohttp/

1. How can I resolve this?
2. What is the best way to manage the 2 versions of `Python` in `Anaconda`?

Comment: Why are you using pip if you have Anaconda?

Comment: Also, try `pip3 install aiohttp`

Comment: Because Anaconda do not have `aiohttp`.

Comment: Not sure why you think that... Did you even try `conda install`? https://anaconda.org/pypi/aiohttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can create new environments, with whatever python and packages you need, for whatever project you are working on.  In this specific instance, if you want to use the aiohttp that requires the higher python, I would do the following:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
source activate py35
pip install aiohttp
```

This will install aiohttp in your py35 environment.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

from [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/).

Comment: You can also try: `conda install -c pypi aiohttp`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) tool to manage your environments(for Python2/Python3) and packages.

See: https://www.continuum.io/content/python-3-support-anaconda for more information.